# Socket doesn't get any data when application is deactivated

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, mobile, air

In my AIR application, on iPad, I don't get any data from connected socket what I deactivate application (press Home/hardware button).

But I know for sure that socket is open.

Any ideas how I can work with socket when my application is deactivated?

ANSWER:

Make sure that you have in your as3 code:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.executeInBackground = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of the code does work:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.executeInBackground = true;
```